# How to exclude ID column when dynamically generating <table> from array of arrays with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, coldfusion

I am using jQuery to make an ajax call to get data from a ColdFusion server. The server queries a database table and returns multiple records as a 2D array. The jQuery code then displays the array values (dynamically) in a `<table>`.

The problem is I don't want to *display* one of the fields: `CustomerID`. Instead, I want to extract that value and use it to create a hyperlink to another page. However, I am unsure of how to tackle this. I thought about using `.map`, `.filter`, and more, but nothing seems to be working and I'm at a standstill. Any ideas?

I hope this makes sense. If I need to make revisions I am happy to do so. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Database Table Columns:**

- InActiveAccount
- CustomerCode
- Customer
- Contact_Person
- Telephone
- FaxNumber
- EmailAddress
- CustomerID

Here is what the 2D array looks like using `console.log(my2Darray)` in Chrome

```
[Array(8)]
0: Array(8)
0: false
1: "tstI"
2: "test Inc"
3: "John Doe"
4: "some phone number"
5: "some fax number"
6: "test@aol.com"
7: 1
length: 8
```

Currently the way the `<table>` is setup is:

```
<table id="response" border="1">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Inactive</th>
    <th>Company Code</th>
    <th>Company Name</th>
    <th>Company Liasion</th>
    <th>Telephone</th>
    <th>Fax</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>false</td>
   <td>tstI</td>
   <td>test Inc</td>
   <td>John Doe</td>
   <td>some telephone number</td>
   <td>some fax number</td>
   <td>test@aol.com</td>
   <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'Search.cfc',
      data: {
        method: 'custCodeData',
        custCode: $('#custCode').val()
      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (data) {
        var array = data.DATA;
        $("#response tr:not(:first)").remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          var newRow = table.insertRow();
          for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
            cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
            console.log(array);
          }
        }
        $("#response tr:contains(true)").css({"background-color": "#ff0000", "color": "#FFF"});
      }
    })
```

Comment: use map and delete

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I don't want to delete, I just want to extract, but do you mind sharing some example code?

Comment: Sorry, I miss read the question. Can you post a full output of the returning data?

Comment: is the output an array of object? or an array of arrays?

Comment: I want to say an array of arrays. Is there a way to know for sure?

Comment: @G.Rose - Just suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3924466) which may help to clarify what you're really asking. Feel free to modify or reject it if you disagree :-)

Comment: @Ageax this edit does help quite a bit. Thank you!

Comment: Can you exclude the data you don't want from the query?

Comment: @Shawn Well no not really. I do need that data to create a hyperlink where the last part relies on the actual customer id. For example: `http://somesite.com/dir1/dir2/index.cfm?Passed_CustomerID=1` where 1 is given from some variable I haven't made yet

Comment: @G.Rose - As an aside, I suspect the reason you're using a 2D array is because that's how CF returns queries by default. Frankly, it's not the most intuitive structure to work with....  Strictly from a code maintenance and readability standpoint, I'd probably return an array of structures from CF. Then access the values by column name instead. `response[i].CustomerCode, `response[i].CustomerID`, etc..  Slightly more code, but far easier to understand and debug 3 months from now...

Comment: @Ageax I agree, that is a much better method of doing this and I will do that from here on out. I've just sunk in too much time into this already and didn't want to rewrite the CFC file. Thank you

Comment: `"...too much time into this already and didn't want to rewrite..."` > While I do feel for this sentiment, more often than I care to admit, my decision to move on from problem code because I felt like I'd spent too much time ended up with me wasting a lot more future time working around the problem code before it became annoying enough to finally go back and fix it. But it's sometimes hard to justify modifying code that "works".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your JQuery code a bit:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'Search.cfc',
      data: {
        method: 'custCodeData',
        custCode: $('#custCode').val()
      },
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (data) {
        var array = data.DATA;
        $("#response tr:not(:first)").remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
          var newRow = table.insertRow();
          for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
            /***** Modification starts from here *****/
            /*If it's customerID of this instance*/
            if(j==7){
              //make your hyperlink, e.g, 
              var link='https://www.customers#'+array[i][j]+'.com';
              cell.innerHTML = link;
            }else{
              cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
            }                
            /***** Modification ends here *****/
          }
        }
        $("#response tr:contains(true)").css({"background-color": "#ff0000", "color": "#FFF"});
      }
    })
```

**Reasoning:**

I suppose you are bit confused with how 2D array works, in your case, there is `array[i][j]` inside of double loops, the outer loop iterates through all the customers, the inner loop iterates through the data of the column `j` of this customer `i`. Hopefully this could be helpful for you to understand the code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification and your reasoning as to why you went this way. Both answers helped, but this one made more sense and was cleaner and explained code

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my english.

As you are using an array with a size of 8 and you know that the position 7 (index 7, from 0 - to 7) is the company id you can exclude it from the loop, something like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var newRow = table.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {

        if(j < 7) {
            var cell = newRow.insertCell(j);
            cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
            console.log(array);
        }

        if(j === 7) {
            cell.innerHTML = `<a href='edit/${array[i][j]}'>go to compay</a>`
        }

    }
}
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is much appreciated! Your code did help alot, but the other user explained his reasoning a bit more. However thank you again!